# GIT - Checking out sometimes incorrectly deletes file in the working area

Tags: git, git-checkout

When checking out branches using git bash on Stash repositories, files in working area disappears. They get marked as deleted (D) and will have to checkout the file again to resolve it. The issue is intermittent. Sometime git stash or rebase helps. Any suggestions on the root cause?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you.  What platform are you running on?  What version of Git are you running?  How did you clone the repository?  Did you move it from somewhere else?  Is it on a network file system?  Do you have any Git hooks set up?  Have you noticed any particular action that brings about the problem?  What kind of files are being removed?  Do you have some process (like anti-virus) that might be removing them?  Have you engaged the Git community at all (https://git-scm.com/community)?

Comment: What platform are you running on? - Stash server (Dc version) run on Linux 
What version of Git are you running? -  Reproduced it on git bash 2.6.3 and Git for Windows 2.10.2.
How did you clone the repository? -  git clone < ssh or https url>.
Did you move it from somewhere else? - No
Is it on a network file system? - Yes, we have NAS to share between the 2 app servers. Repo is on NAS.
Do you have any Git hooks set up? - some for entire infra
Have you noticed any particular action that brings about the problem? so far switch branches and rebase

Comment: What kind of files are being removed? Do you have some process (like anti-virus) that might be removing them? *.cd and *.csproj
Have you engaged the Git community at all? - Yes, no responses yet. - Prabhu

Comment: It'd be best to add that information to your description of the problem rather than leave it in the comments.  That way it's more readily available for others to see.  Also, I meant is your working tree on a network file system?  And the Git hooks was about local ones--things your working copy would trigger, like a `post-checkout` or `post-rewrite` hook?  A `post-checkout` hook would be called after changing branches and the `post-rewrite` hook after rebasing.  So if you have some logic in one of them, it might be that it's not behaving as expected.